# Observable.timer(0,10000) after unsubscribed still it is getting called on other component in production build

Tags: environment-variables, angular5, angular-builder, webpack-production

I am calling one API every 10 sec using Observable.timer(0,10000) and unsubscribing on ngOnDestroy() method.But this call is not getting stopped and its keep getting adds in the queue and calling even after leaving that component.

I have tried to destroy the component on `ngOnDestroy()` function. But it's still its getting call.

it should have called only on this component and should call once every 10 seconds but if we go to other component call is getting added in the queue and once come back to instance component it is calling multiple time every 10 secs.

Code:

```
this._instanceSub = Observable.timer(0,reference.INSTANCE_CALL_INTERVAL) .subscribe(() => { this.getComonentInstance(this.componentId); }); ngOnDestroy() { 
if (this._instanceSub) { 
    this._instanceSub.unsubscribe(); 
}
```

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: this._instanceSub = Observable.timer(0,reference.INSTANCE_CALL_INTERVAL)
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.getComonentInstance(this.componentId);
        });




ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this._instanceSub) {
      this._instanceSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

The above code must work i have used the below code for the same

```
this.subject = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  timer(0, reference.INSTANCE_CALL_INTERVAL).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.subject),
  ).subscribe(t => this.getComonentInstance(this.componentId));
}
```

and in ngOndestroy

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subject.next();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried like this too but still problem persist in prod build. So basically it is dynamic component which is being generate on tab click but I have tried to destroy it whenever I am leaving that component.
I can check in DOM in scope it is still there even when I am on different component.